# change src depends on click coordinate

Tags: jquery

hi im still new with jquery. I try to create a function where i click on some coordinate, it will show different image. my code already work.but i still trying to make the code cleaner and more reusable. but i kinda stuck. im really appreciate if one of you guys want to lend a hand and help me to make this code better. thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/ewtt0kzg/

```js
$('.main-image').click(function(e) {
  var main_image = $(this);
  var topleft = $(this).siblings('.single-page-image').eq(0).attr('src');
  var botLeft = $(this).siblings('.single-page-image').eq(1).attr('src');
  var botRight = $(this).siblings('.single-page-image').eq(2).attr('src');
  var topRight = $(this).siblings('.single-page-image').eq(3).attr('src');
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
  var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
  if (relativeY < (height / 2) && relativeX < (width / 2)) {
    main_image.attr('src', topleft);
  }
  if (relativeY < (height / 2) && relativeX > (width / 2)) {
    main_image.attr('src', topRight);
  }
  if (relativeY > (height / 2) && relativeX < (width / 2)) {
    main_image.attr('src', botLeft);
  }
  if (relativeY > (height / 2) && relativeX > (width / 2)) {
    main_image.attr('src', botRight);
  }
});
```

```css
.second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="single-page">
  <img class="single-page-image main-image" src="https://learn.getgrav.org/system/images/media/thumb-jpg.png" />

  <img class="single-page-image second top-left" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1bBMTxUs4iRTG/giphy.gif" />

  <img class="single-page-image second bottom-left" src="https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png" />

  <img class="single-page-image second top-right" src="http://hubblesite.org/home-page/graphics/middle_container/Homepage-announce-gallery-400x400.png" />

  <img class="single-page-image second top-left" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/560aa49ee4b0b632352fe46f/t/560d517de4b08ac155043394/1457617167699/" />
</section>
```

Comment: There's a separate code review forum. Please post your question there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review forum.

Comment: where, im sorry but i dont know where

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/